# How to make a function to replace an element if it has changed

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a function which creates elements (if they don't exist) or delete + create (replace) (if they exist).

For the moment I can create them well, but `removeChild()` does not work. Thanks for your help.

```js
function editerElement() {
    let attributs = {
        valeur: ['inputTitre', 'inputH1', 'inputCouleurH1', 'inputP'],
        id: ['titre', 'h1', 'couleurH1', 'p'],
        element: ['title', 'h1', 'input', 'p'],
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        if (document.getElementById(attributs.valeur[i]) && document.getElementById(attributs.valeur[i]).value != '') {
            var valeur = document.getElementById(attributs.valeur[i]).value;
            var ancienneValeur = document.getElementById(attributs.id[i]);
            var nouvelleValeur = document.createElement(attributs.element[i]);
            nouvelleValeur.id = attributs.id[i];
            nouvelleValeur.innerHTML = valeur;
            if (ancienneValeur && ancienneValeur.id === 'titre') {
                // document.head.removeChild(ancienneValeur);
                document.head.appendChild(nouvelleValeur);
            } else {
                // document.head.removeChild(ancienneValeur);
                document.body.appendChild(nouvelleValeur);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have one in the head, and others for the body.

the function which calls this function:

```js
function editerPage() {
    let div = document.createElement('div');
    div.id = 'div';
    document.body.appendChild(div);
    var bouton = document.createElement('button');
    bouton.innerHTML = 'Valider';
    bouton.setAttribute('onclick', 'editerElement()');
    let attributes = {
        type: ['input', 'input', 'input', 'input'],
        id: ['Titre', 'H1', 'CouleurH1', 'P'],
        placeholder: ['Titre de l\'onglet de la page', 'Titre h1 de la page', 'Changer la couleur du titre h1', 'Paragraphe de la page'],
        click: ['titre()', 'h1()', 'couleurH1()', 'p()'],
        class: ['col-6', 'col-6', 'col-2', 'col-6']
    };
    for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++ ){
        var divElement = document.createElement('div');
        div.classList.add('div' + attributes.id);
        // var bouton = document.createElement('button');
        // bouton.innerHTML = 'Valider';
        // bouton.setAttribute('onclick', attributes.click);
        var element = document.createElement(attributes.type[i]);
        element.id = 'input' + attributes.id[i];
        element.setAttribute('placeholder', attributes.placeholder[i]);
        element.classList.add(attributes.class[i]);
        if (attributes.id[i] === 'inputCouleurH1') {
            element.setAttribute('type', 'color');
            var label = document.createElement('label');
            label.classList.add('col-4');
            label.innerHTML = 'Changer la couleur du h1';
            divElement.appendChild(label);
        }
        div.appendChild(divElement);
        // divElement.appendChild(bouton);
        divElement.appendChild(element);
    }
    divElement.appendChild(bouton);
    document.getElementById('customCheck1').setAttribute('onclick', 'editerPageOff()')
}
```

Comment: Have you two elements with the same id ( since you are searching in the DOM with getElementById)?

Comment: If I create a new element before deleting the old one, yes, but precisely I want to delete this old elements before creating the new one.

Comment: Ciao @Franck Valet. This is the second part of yesterday [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63308708/create-multiple-elements-in-a-for-loop/). I saw that you are using my solution. At least mark it as valid...

Comment: Still unclear to me, sorry. Have you the chance to post the html you have to manipulate?

Comment: Initially there is no html.  It is created in this function and must be modified by this same function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only have a problem with removing childs, there is a general way to achieve that. Just use the remove function I provided.

```js
function remove(element) {
  if (element instanceof HTMLElement && element.parentNode) {
    element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
  }
}
```

**Example:**

```js
function remove(element) {
  if (element instanceof HTMLElement && element.parentNode) {
    element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
  }
}

document.getElementById("rma").onclick = () => {
  remove(document.getElementById("a"))
}

document.getElementById("rmb").onclick = () => {
  remove(document.getElementById("b"))
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div id="a">a</div>
  <div id="b">b</div>
</div>
<div>
  <button id="rma">Remove a</button>
  <button id="rmb">Remove b</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

@Tom Siegel it's work, i have made some modifications:

```js
            if (ancienneValeur && ancienneValeur.id === 'titre') {
                remove(document.getElementById(ancienneValeur.id));
                document.head.appendChild(nouvelleValeur);
            } else if (ancienneValeur && ancienneValeur.id != 'titre') {
                document.body.appendChild(div);
                remove(document.getElementById(ancienneValeur.id));
                div.appendChild(nouvelleValeur);
            } else {
                document.body.appendChild(div);
                div.appendChild(nouvelleValeur);
            }
```

but maybe you know how i can include remove() in my first function ?

Comment: So in case of replacing or creating just call the remove function like you already do after you created the id `remove(document.getElementById(ancienneValeur.id));`. it will remove the already existing elements with the given id. After that you can insert your new element.